# Is it possible to check a cast from Object to Map<String, List<Object>>?

Tags: java, types, casting, playframework-2.1

I'm importing test data into my Play application from a YAML file. The data is stored in the file as a Map, with Strings for keys, and Lists of objects for values, like so: `Map<String, List<Object>>`. Each key specifies a List of a different type of object.

When I import the file into Java, I have to cast the result as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> testData = ( Map<String, List<Object>> ) Yaml
            .load( "test-data.yml" );
```

Then I save each type of object individually using `Ebean.save( all.get( <key> ) );`

The problem is that I'm getting a warning for an unchecked cast. I'm supressing the warning at the moment, because I'll always be providing a `Map<String, List<Object>>`, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can check the type before I cast it?

Comment: Don't worry about the warnings. Just suppress it. You'll get that warning every time you try to typecast to a concrete parameterized type.

Comment: OK, so I can expect this every time? I see. OK, thanks for the information!